how to achieve zero-downtime deployment with pm2
I have a project involving a YAML file for deployment, and the flow is as follows:
Pull Changes: The YAML file pulls all the changes.
Start Temporary Instance: It starts a temporary instance to handle incoming requests.
Restart Main Process: While the temporary instance is active, the main process is stopped and restarted.
Stop Temporary Instance: After the main process restarts, the temporary instance is stopped.
I implemented this flow to achieve zero downtime during deployment, ensuring that the service continues to accept requests. However, I'm encountering an issue where requests sent to the temporary instance may result in an infinite loop if that instance is stopped before the request is processed.
How can I address this problem, or are there any improved approaches to achieve zero downtime during deployment? Please explain in detail.
here the workflow file script
script: |
            cd /var/www/my-api-prod/
            git reset --hard
            git checkout PROD
            git pull origin PROD
            yarn
            npm install
            export NODE_ENV=PROD
            yarn prisma-all
            yarn build
            pm2 start "/var/www/my-api-prod/dist/src/main.js" --name="my-api-prod-temp" -i 1
            pm2 save
            sleep 30
            pm2 stop "my-api-prod" -s
            pm2 start "/var/www/my-api-prod/dist/src/main.js" --name="my-api-prod" -i 1
            pm2 save
            sleep 30
            pm2 stop my-api-prod-temp
            pm2 save


Side note, NODE_ENV=PROD is not a valid option. You want production. You are also using both yarn and npm to install?

yes I don't want face any issue that's why I'm using both

You are creating issues using both

can you explain how and what can I do for improvements or else do you know any other tools like pm2

There is no need to use two package managers in the same project. Pick one: yarn, bun, npm, pnpm...

okay, or do you have any solutions related to the problem I have shared about zero-downtime
